# Apache Flink - Update configuration within operator without using Broadcast state

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are using flink to make http calls for every event and this requires certain data that is stored in a db.
This data is updated about once a week. This update has to go to the operator.

Is there any way to update this data within the operator without using the Broadcast stream as we are trying to keep the number of streams low in our architecture and also because the changes in the data are in-frequent?

Comment: To be honest, using Broadcast or Connected streams seems to be the best solution here as this provides best performance and security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible options:

A) You could simply use a `ProcessFunction` with a timer and pull for changes every X minutes.

B) If your state is small and restarts are not too critical: Your server requests robably fails if you do not update your data (403?). Then you could just load the data in `open` and fail your operator when you receive 403s and recover.

edit:

An example to how A) could work. Assuming you have

Source(Record)->MyAsyncFunc(Output)->Sink(Output)

I'd go and add another function

Source(Record)->ConfFetcher(Tuple2(Record, Conf))->MyAsyncFunc(Output)->Sink(Output)

edit2:

As you pointed out in the comments a Flink timer is bound to a keyed state.  However, for this use case, we don't need to use any Flink timer at all and just use Java Timers.

```
private static class PullConfig<T> extends RichMapFunction<T, Tuple2<T, Conf>> {
    private transient ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    private transient volatile Conf conf;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);

        service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::pullConfig, 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }

    void pullConfig() {
        conf = ...
    }


    @Override
    public Tuple2<T, Conf> map(T value) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple2(value, conf);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Arvind Heise. Restarting operators is not an option as the event volume is high and the data that is being used does not necessarily cause a failure when outdated. We are using async IO operator on a non-keyed stream. Would it be possible to fit in the process function into this?

Comment: A) is a reasonable solution but this basically means that You don't have any guarantee, that you will always use the most recent data. Not sure how critical is this for Your use case.

Comment: Thanks @DominikWosiński, Our updates are very in-frequent and there is no necessity for it to be updated instantly.

Comment: @Arvind Heise, Apologies if my ignorance is unbearable. But since my stream is non-keyed, I'm unable to implement the process function. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is `DataStream#process` not working on non-keyed data for you? What's the error?

Comment: @Arvind Heise, I've got this "Setting timers is only supported on a keyed streams".

Comment: @Arvind Heise, it says that here also : https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of that limitation, but I'll update my answer with the use of Java executors.

Comment: @Arvind Heise, thanks for all the help and the patience.

Comment: @Arvind Heise, If I set the parallelism as 8, there will be 8 instances of the conf getting created and might lead to consistency issues for the events flowing the same stream. Hence, I'm setting the variable as static and I'm initializing the executor service in a static block. On testing, it does not seem to create any issues. Will this be safe? Do you forsee any issues?

Comment: `static` makes more sense, as you'd only want to retain it once per process. However, note that across different computation nodes, the same issue appears again. If inconsistencies are an issue, I'd strongly suggest to go back to broadcast.